# Is there an elegant way to trace a printed statement to the line of code that printed it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a quick way to recognize a print line.
For example, in JS there is console.trace() that gives you an easy indication of where the print came from.

I know I can print a traceback but it is just too big for the task and makes following the code execution almost impossible.
I need something that wouldn't take a lot of room when printed and will point me to the correct line where that output was printed.

Comment: What is being printed out? Can you not copy and search for it in your code?

Comment: Have you considered using the `logging` module…?

Comment: @Sam There are places I want to only print a variable's content and not other strings so I can't trace a unique string.

Comment: @deceze I already have heavy use of the logging module.
I know it can print the method from which the logging occurred but I want something that is separated visually from the logs

Comment: Using `logging` as @deceze suggested you can modify your print format to include the module and line number of printed message

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are actually trying to achieve, and how what you have tried so far doesn’t work?

Comment: I think I will go with a dedicated logger, Thank you!

Comment: you think you will go with a dedicated logger but you accepted the answer without a logger?

Comment: This is hilarious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the logging module as shown by @hiroprotagonist is probably the way to go, but because you mentioned you already have heavy use of logging, you could maybe want to use the `inspect` module.

This example will print the function where the print statement under `DEBUG` is executed; maybe this is sufficient for your needs?

```
DEBUG = True

if DEBUG:
    import inspect

    def _print(s):
        print(f'now in: {inspect.stack()[1][3]} -> {s}')


def current_function():
    if DEBUG:
        _print('debug stuff')
    print('doing stuff')


def main():
    current_function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### output:

```
now in: current_function -> debug stuff
doing stuff
```

Comment: oh. that seems a bit simpler!

Comment: haha, thank you @hiroprotagonist - I like your logging approach better, but sometimes, a simple approach is good too! I think a decorator would work well too.

Answer (score 6):

using the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging) you could try this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=("line %(lineno)d: %(message)s"))

def print_line(strg):
    logging.debug(strg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_line("test")
```

which outputs

```
line 18: test
```

---

should this interfere with the rest of your logging you can also create and configure a dedicated logger (there may be better ways to do this)

```
import logging
import sys

print_line_logger = logging.getLogger("print_line")
print_line_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter("line %(lineno)d: %(message)s")
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
print_line_logger.addHandler(handler)


def print_line(strg):
    print_line_logger.debug(strg)
```

Comment: This is the better answer; the suggestion in my own answer works, but is probably more suited for quick and dirty projects.